# How can I check that a referenced assembly is available at runtime?

Tags: c#

I am creating a simple, standalone .net winforms app. It references the assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement` of .Net Framework 4 that may or may not be present on a client's machine. If that assembly is not present, then at run time I would like my app to fail gracefully and not crash.

I have a component that starts:

```
...
using Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement;
...
try {
    // do something that uses SqlWmiManagement
}
catch {
    // handle the missing assembly
}
```

Unfortunately, an unhandled exception is thrown as the component loads, way before my little try block.

What is the correct way to do this?

There's no installer, this should be a drag-and-drop exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved this by correcting the scope in my code. Working from this article:

https://sites.google.com/site/craigandera/craigs-stuff/clr-workings/dealing-with-assembly-load-failure

I moved the method that requires `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement` into a separate class. Separating it means I can call it from inside a `try {}` block that starts before the scope that causes the assembly to be implicitly loaded. That means I can catch the exception from a failed assembly load.

Instead of:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement;

// .net implicitly loads assembly when current class is instantiated

// ... code ...

try {
   // problem method using missing assembly
} 
catch {
   // this is ineffective because the ass'y load already failed before the try block
}
```

I was able to:

```
try {
    // invoke problem method in another class
    // implicitly loads assembly here instead, inside the try block 
} 
catch {
    // this now catches ass'y load failure
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If an assembly is not found, then the AssemblyResolve event will fire. You can try catching that and exiting the app there. [See this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx).

```
public static void Main()
{
    // Note: AssemblyResolve occurs when the resolution of an assembly fails.
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);
}

private static Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if ( args.Name.Contains("SqlWmiManagement"))
    {
        // assembly not found
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is my favorite answer so far.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is thrown when the function is JIT'd.  Change your code to:

```
void DoSomethingThatUsesSqlWmiManagement_()
{
   ...
}
void DoSomethingThatUsesSqlWmiManagement()
{
   try
   { 
          DoSomethingThatUsesSqlWmiManagement_();
   }
   catch
   {   
            handle the missing assembly
   }
}
```

You probably should `catch` only the specific `Exception`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the class which contains your Main() function does not reference anything related to the assembly.

If it is defined as part of your main form, take it out in its own class.

Then, at the very beginning of the method use Assembly.Load(). You would have to pass a fully qualified name of the SqlWmiManagement.dll assembly as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, this answer got me much closer

Answer (score 0):

While @CC Inc's answer works when the reference is loaded after `Main()` is called, for a reference using a static object or class, the `ResolveEventHandler` needs to be installed before `Main()` is called. You can try:

```
private static bool gAutoLoad = ExecuteBeforeMain();

private static bool ExecuteBeforeMain()
{
    // Note: AssemblyResolve only occurs when the resolution of an assembly fails.
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolveErrorHandler;
    return true;
}

private static System.Reflection.Assembly AssemblyResolveErrorHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{ ... }
```

I do not think that there is a guarantee that `ExecuteBeforeMain()` is executed early enough (before the reference is trying to be loaded), but it worked for me when I included my logger with is used like this:

```
ReferenceNamespace.LoggerClass.StaticActiveLogger.LogMethod(string);
```